# Angular 2 | Typescript | Mapping an string to a component name and return component

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object

I got  list of components that I would like to replace on certain conditions:

List of navigation components:

```
import {navigationDefaultComponent} from '';
import {navigationSmoothComponent} from '';
import {navigationMobileComponent} from '';

navigations: [
{component: navigationDefaultComponent},
{component: navigationSmoothComponent},
{component: navigationMobileComponent},
]
```

I have an object that comes from API and tel's me what component I should show

```
const X = {
name: 'John Smith',
navigation: 'navigationDefaultComponent'
}
```

I have done it this way, as I can't store the component in the api. The API can not return me a component. If there is a way please do let me know.
So my goal is is to have a const that will go through navigation object and based on x.navigation string will map and return me the component.

```
const nav = ????
```

Comment: I don't understand. Is it for routing? Do you have a routing Module?

Comment: Don't think of what comes down as being a component; that's an internal design issue, not anything the server should be aware of. Think of it as being a **route**. Then just navigate to it using `this.route.navigate`.

Comment: I got a profile page and I would like to load in the same place different type of components. In the same location, just different type of components. so instead of having a huge list of *ngIf, or switches. I loading them dynamically. I now try to figure how to define what to load via API or via mapping to a list of components.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a typical situation.
You would need to make one of your component to listen to ** route and then use dynamic component loading. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

You can create an array having string and Component

```
let mapping = [
    {'name':'name1', 'component':Component1},
    {'name':'name2', 'component':Component2},
    {'name':'name3', 'component':Component3},
    {'name':'name4', 'component':Component4},
    {'name':'name5', 'component':Component5},
];
```

Please Note that Component1, Component2 are direct reference to the Component and not their string representations.

Create a directive, to be included in your AppComponent

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[app-directive]',
})
export class AppDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Include the directive in your template

```
<ng-template app-directive></ng-template>
```

Get the reference to your directive in ts file

```
@ViewChild(AppDirective) appDirective: AppDirective;
```

Now load the desired component after getting the response from the API

```
// let's assume name1 is what API returned
let component = this.mapping['name1'];
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(mapping[component);
let viewContainerRef = this.appDirective.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();

let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

I hope this solves your problem...

Comment: this.mapping['name1']; returns undifiened.